# Cauchy product of power series with $x^{2n}$

Tags: real-analysis, taylor-expansion, cauchy-product

I am trying to rewrite a function $y(x)=\frac{1}{1+x+x^2+x^3}$ as a series. I used geometric series and got to two power series that I need to Cauchy product, however, one of them has $x^{2n}$ and I cannot find anywhere how to do it.
Here is the the product that I am trying to solve
$$(\sum_{n=0}^\infty{(-1)^n x^n})(\sum_{n=0}^\infty{(-1)^n x^{2n}})$$

Comment: What if you multiply top and bottom by $(1-x)$? You would get $(1-x)/(1-x^4)$. Then you can expand $1/(1-x^4)$ which contains only powers which are multiples of $4$ and finally multiplication by $(1-x)$ should be easy (sum of the series with a shifted version of it)

Comment: $1-x+{{x}^{4}}-{{x}^{5}}+{{x}^{8}}-{{x}^{9}}+{{x}^{12}}-{{x}^{13}}+{{x}^{16}}-{{x}^{17}}+{{x}^{20}}+\mbox{...}$

Comment: @GReyes good idea and I will propably use it, however, I would still like to know how  to deal witch Cauchy product such as this so that if I come accros something similar I will be able to solve it